# How to add a transparent gif sprite in pygame

Tags: pygame, transparency

I'd like to add a transparent gif sprite in pygame? Any help?

When I add any gif it has a black box around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you converted the surface using convert_alpha()?

You would usually load an image like so:

```
sprite_image = pygame.image.load("image.gif").convert_alpha()
```

Comment: PyGame does not support animated GIFs, see http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html. In game development you don't want to use that either, you would rather use spritesheets and create your own animated sprite class. This might be helpful: http://shinylittlething.com/2009/07/21/pygame-and-animated-sprites/

Comment: Hmm yes ok,im still in the early stages of game development..2 months in..How would I animate a simple image to change every second between 2 images?

Comment: You can use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to count millisecond since last image change and if one second left than change it again (and save `pygame.time.get_ticks()` in variable `last_change`to compare it with current `pygame.time.get_ticks()` in every loop)

Comment: Or you could use custom event with `pygame.time.set_timer()`